# Can I use "consistent with" in this way? If not, what can I use instead?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, american-english

I want to write a sentence like

> Consistent with my previous experience, I am interested in pursuing research ~ blah blah.

Here, I know that this sentence is grammatically incorrect and I cannot use "consistent" in the very first part of the sentence because it is adjective. 
Is there any other word or way that can produce the same meaning? 
Any comments or advice would be appreciated! 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I do not think that what you have written is grammatically incorrect. However are you sure that *consistent* is the word you need? Your wish to pursue research may indeed be consistent with your previous experience, but as I think you sense the word doesn't seem quite right in that position. I think I would actually turn the sentence around and say *I am interested in pursuing research into the love lives of leprechauns, which is consistent with (or 'follows on from') my previous experience*.

Comment: your comment helped me a lot. I just wanted to emphasize that the research that I am going to pursue is consistent with my previous experience. That was the reason why I inverted the order of this sentence.  If i want to emphasize "consistent", is it okay to write that sentence with that order?
Does this sentence sound weird to you?

Comment: Have you thought, perhaps of saying: *It would be consistent with my previous experience to pursue research in....*?. You may find that it will help your case also to identify some element of the job for which you are applying which will further enhance the scope of your experience.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the front-shifted modifier [dangles](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/597/1/): it is not *I* but rather the future *research* that can more properly be termed *consistent* with the previous experience. Thus a possible correction would be

> Consistent with my previous experience, the research that I am interested in pursuing . . .

or

> Consistent with my previous experience, my research interests include . . .

Comment: Thank you for your comments! it makes sense now!
but how about other options like

1. In accordance with my previous research experience, I am interested in pursuing research related to blah blah ~~

2. According to my previous research experience, I am interested in pursuing research related to blah blah ~~ 

3. In conformity with my previous research experience, I am interested in pursuing research related to blah blah ~~

How do you think about these options? do theses sentences sound weird and ungrammatical?

Comment: one more option, sorry!
4. Based on my previous research experience, I am interested in pursuing research related to blah blah ~~.

and if some of these sound okay, which option is the best?, If all of these options do not make sense, I will go with your suggestion! Thank you in advance!

Comment: All of these alternatives have the same dangling problem, since that which accords or conforms with the previous experience is still the proposed new research, not the reasearcher. If you want to retain yourself as subject of the main clause, try something like "As you might surmise from my previous research experience," or "In following through on my previous research experience, I . . ." (since the one *following through* would indeed be the researcher).

Comment: Thank you so much your comments! professor! so what you are saying is "consistent" itself in the very first part of the sentence is okay to use if i solve the dangling problem. Am i right? I thought using "consistent" in the very first part of the sentence would be wrong because it is adjective haha.

Comment: Yes, you are right.